# Install Node 0.12.x binaries on Centos 7

Tags: linux, centos, node.js

As of this post, there don't appear to be any `yum` or `rpm` options for available for installing NodeJS 0.12.x. Even Node's semi-official yum repo (nodesource.com) is still on 0.10.x for RHEL distros.

So two alternatives, build from source or download the binary distribution. First I'm going to try the binaries:

http://nodejs.org/dist/v0.12.4/node-v0.12.4-linux-x64.tar.gz

After untarring, what do I do with it? I know there are `node` and `npm` executables. Is there anything else I need to know about? Where do I move everything and what needs to be symlinked? Where is the proper place for these files to live on the server?

Comment: The first question to ask is: Can you really not live without 0.12.x?

Comment: I'm trying to use libraries that require an updated version. 0.10.x is like 2 years old and is missing a lot of modern features (hince one of the reasons io.js was spun off).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is in that tarball's `README.md` file:

```
cd /usr/local && tar --strip-components 1 -xzf \
                /path/to/node-<version>-<platform>-<arch>.tar.gz
```

This basically extracts the contents to /usr/local. I would further expand that by adding the arguments `--exclude=ChangeLog --exclude=LICENSE --exclude=README.md` to the tar command to prevent the documentation from being written to `/usr/local`.